# Why does my SVG generated with svg.js have a "strange margin"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg.js

I want to create a web application consisting of a header, footer, and left and right sidebar layout, where the size is set according to the children, and a main container that fills the rest of the available space. The main container is used by svg.js.
I don't want any scrollbars, and I don't want the footer to move down whilst the svg fills the entire main container.

I have achieved this to some extent, but one problem remains:
When I set the size of the svg generated by svg.js to `100%`, the layout works, but some things don't (like panzoom, etc.).

So I decided to programatically resize the svg to fit the container. But then a strange margin "pushes" the footer down and a scrollbar is shown.
I don't understand why this border/padding/margin exists - inspecting the element shows no indication that there is a border or padding.

How can I set the size in absolute pixels so that it looks the same as the relative 100% height value?

I have created a code pen to illustrate the problem. The value of OFFSET needed to shorten the height so that no scrollbar is displayed (the height of the "weird border") seems to vary (with zoom factor, window size, etc.).
https://codepen.io/kai-dj/pen/wvYwELE

This is what I'd expect (using 100% for height):

[image: how it should look]

This is how it looks when using an appropriate offset value:

[image: how it looks with offset]

This is how it looks with sizing by parent without any offset:

[image: Showing scrollbar and margin]

The red part is a rect size set to the same size as used with `svg.size()`, the orange part is the background-color of svg-elements set via css - blue is footers background color and white the right sidebar.

Comment: Please post the code in the question (you can use a Stack Snippet to make it runnable) rather than an offsite link.

Comment: An `<svg>` is `display: inline` by default, causing a slight space line below sometimes (the same goes for `<img>`). Defining `svg { display: block }` solves that.

Comment: Rene van der Lende - `disply:block` does the trick, thank you. Please transfer your comment to an answer, so I can select it as solution.
Question aside: Besides "just knowing" that inline can cause that line - could I have seen this with developer tools? 
Ryan M - the SO-code-snippet did not work for me - I'll look into the docs for it and edit eventually.